# Qiskit statevector_simulator returns different results

Tags: qiskit, vqe

I'm running VQE algorithm from qiskit aqua on `statevector_simulator` and each time I run it I get different results which are sometimes correct and sometimes not. I'm not sure if I'm setting parameters correctly.

Here is my code:

The `qubitOp` is generated with DOcplex module.

```
max_trials = 80
depth = 1
entanglement='full'

slsqp = SLSQP(maxiter=max_trials)
ry = RY(qubitOp.num_qubits, depth=depth, entanglement=entanglement)
vqe = VQE(qubitOp, ry, slsqp)
provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend,seed_simulator=seed, seed_transpiler=seed, optimization_level=0)
res = vqe.run(quantum_instance)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VQE has an initial_point parameter, which is the starting point it uses for the optimization. In the absence on one being provided (or suggested via the variational form) it will pick a random one. You can seed Aqua, like you did the simulator, so it will end up with the same random one each time, to get a predictable outcome. Add the following to do this before using any Aqua algorithms etc.

```
from qiskit.aqua import aqua_globals

aqua_globals.random_seed = seed
```

Now since your result varies it suggests anyway that you are not reaching a minimum and the optimization loop is ending early. More iterations of the optimizer may be needed and/or you may need to look at the variational form, say larger depth with what is being used.